# Django + AJAX abort executing funtion

Tags: django, ajax

I am using ajax to run a django function. In this function, I connect to the database and run a sql statement, the result of which is saved to a csv file. This sql takes a long time to run at times, and I would like to be able to interrupt this function on demand. Is it possible? Can I get the id of the running process or request and use it to kill it?

Comment: killing the process does not sound like the right thing to do. How about you'd focus on optimizing the db query instead?

Comment: The sql statement is complex and its execute sometime very long and it's ok.
Sometime I need to abort execution because for example i forgot do something before.  run sql is second process, and before it I need to do a several operation

Comment: Are you saying destroy the Ajax request after some time? Save your Ajax call like `let blah = $.ajax({...})` then just do `blah.abort()`

Comment: If you're talking about killing the Django request itself, I'm not sure that's entirely possible if you're in the middle of an operation. I guess you could try to wrap your SQL operation in a try/except clause that allows for interruption. Django has a neat rollback feature for its ORM/db ops. You'd just need a way to interrupt it (e.g. KeyboardInterruption).